# Detect phone number in Lex/Lambda from a Twilio SMS service

Tags: lambda, twilio, amazon-lex

I'm building a chatbot using `Twilio` -> `Lex` -> `Lambda` -> `DynamoDB`.
I would like to capture the phone number of the party that initiated the chat so I can contact them again later (if they opt in). Unfortunately, I can't figure out what I need to do so that Lambda can see this value and write it to DynamoDB.

Based on this documentation, the value exists and is readable in [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters): 
... I'm just not sure how to read from Lex and send to Lambda. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, when you connect Twilio to Lex and Lex to a Lambda function, Lex will set a couple of [Request Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html#context-mgmt-request-attribs) specific to the platform. Request attributes appear in the [input event that is sent to the Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html) under the `requestAttributes` key.

The [from phone number that sent the message to the Twilio number appears as the `user-id` attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/example1.html). But note, all attributes sent through by Lex take the `x-amz-lex:` namespace. So you can read the phone number from the input event as:

```
event['requestAttributes']['x-amz-lex:user-id']
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Get it from:

```
event['requestAttributes']['sessionId']
```

The sessionId value will be something like "whatsapp:573000000000".